# Get randomly weighted averages between samples in a batch, with arbitrary sample shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensor

Essentially, I want an implementation of [this custom Keras layer](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/636ec0533df1d1ba2bfe4ec9ae7aa66bd7ee2177/wgan_gp/wgan_gp.py#L26):

```
class RandomWeightedAverage(_Merge):
    """Provides a (random) weighted average between real and generated image samples"""
    def _merge_function(self, inputs):
        alpha = K.random_uniform((32, 1, 1, 1))
        return (alpha * inputs[0]) + ((1 - alpha) * inputs[1])
```

but with arbitrary batch size and no dependence on the shape of the data. The intention of that layer is to merge two batches by taking the average of each pair of samples, but randomly weighting each averaging. The issues with that implementation are:

1. It has a hardcoded batch size of 32. In my model, the batch size is currently not defined at the time that I create the layer. I could change it so that batch size is defined earlier, but I'd really prefer not to.
2. If assumes that each sample in a batch is a rank-3 tensor, because it was originally intended for images. I have two types of data that I'll be using in my model, one of which is images with shape (28, 28, 1), and the other of which is vectors with shape (100,). I'd prefer to not make two `RandomWeightedAverage` layer implementations.

How can I make a `random_uniform` tensor of shape `[batch_size] + [1] * rank_of_samples`? Or, more abstractly, is there another way to accomplish the same goal of merging two batches by taking randomly weighted averages of each pair of samples?

Things I've tried:

1. ```
   alpha = K.random_uniform(K.shape(inputs[0])[0])
   ```

   Anything of that sort wouldn't work because two tensors must be the same rank to be multiplied, even if they don't have exactly the same shape. For example, tensors shaped like `(32,)` and `(32, 28, 28, 1)` cannot be multiplied, but `(32, 1, 1, 1)` and `(32, 28, 28, 1)` can.
2. ```
   in_shape = K.shape(inputs[0])
   shape = K.concatenate([in_shape[0], K.ones_like(in_shape[1:], dtype='int32')], axis=0)
   alpha = K.random_uniform(shape)
   ```

   Doesn't work, giving the slightly confusing error:

   ```
   ValueError: Can't concatenate scalars (use tf.stack instead) for 'random_weighted_average_1/concat' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes: [], [3], [].
   ```
3. ```
   in_shape = K.shape(inputs[0])
   shape = K.ones_like(in_shape, dtype='int32')
   shape[0] = in_shape[0]
   alpha = K.random_uniform(shape)
   ```

   Doesn't work, giving the error:

   ```
   TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment
   ```

Keras 2.3.0, TF 1.14.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was close with attempt #2. In the code in the question, `in_shape[0]` is a scalar, and I was trying to concatenate it with `K.ones_like(in_shape[1:], dtype='int32')`, which is a vector. Simply changing `in_shape[0]` to `in_shape[0:1]` was enough to fix the error and compile my model successfully.

Final code:

```
class RandomWeightedAverage(layers.merge._Merge):
    """Provides a (random) weighted average between real and generated image samples"""
    def _merge_function(self, inputs):
        in_shape = K.shape(inputs[0])
        shape = K.concatenate([in_shape[0:1], K.ones_like(in_shape[1:], dtype='int32')], axis=0)
        alpha = K.random_uniform(shape)
        return (alpha * inputs[0]) + ((1 - alpha) * inputs[1])
```

I'm not sure that this is the best way to do this, but at the very least it appears to work.